Never converging phonon calculation in a supercell (Quantum ESPRESSO)
I'm trying to calculate with Quantum ESPRESSO the phonons at the Gamma Point of a Supercell of rutile. I have generated the supercell itself with VESTA and I have tested the convergence for a 2x2x2 k-mesh supercell with a serie of pw.x calculation.
Then I'm trying to calculate phonons with ph.x but the calculation stops. I've tried to change several parameters, according to what found on the web, because anytime I get different errors without any crucial resolution.
Could you explain what kind of general features do I have to consider in using the supercell? In terms of diagonalization, and so on...
My most common error are

Error in routine cdiaghg (100): problems computing cholesky
Error in routine cdiaghg (542): S matrix not positive definite
or simply the calculation doesn't converge after days in a HPC of the university.

I'm attaching here my input, just in case
&Inputph
  outdir    = './'
  prefix    = 'supercell'
  fildyn    = 'supercell.dmat'
  lraman    = .true.
  recover   = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
  diagonalization = 'cg'
  tr2_ph    =  1.0d-14
/
0.0 0.0 0.0

and what's more for the pw.x
&CONTROL
    calculation = "scf"
    max_seconds =  8.64000e+04
    pseudo_dir  = "./UPF/pseudo_lda_ncpp"
    prefix = "supercell"
    verbosity = "high"
/

&SYSTEM
    celldm(1)                 =  17.166332566254404
    celldm(3)                 =  0.6430803241473297
    cosAB                     =  0.
    cosBC                     =  0.
    cosAC                     =  0.
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  6.5000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  9.00000e+00
    ibrav                     =  6
    nat                       =  48
    ntyp                      =  2
    occupations               =  fixed
/


&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-06
    electron_maxstep = 200
    mixing_beta      =  5.00000e-01
    startingpot      = "atomic"
    startingwfc      = "atomic+random"
/

K_POINTS {automatic}
2 2 2 0 0 0

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ti   47.86700  Ti.upf
O    15.99940  O.upf

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Ti ... ... ... 
....

for the pw.x.
Thank you in advance!
Best Wishes
Martino

Have you tried simply not using a supercell and instead choose more k points and q points?

I'd like to, but my aim is to go toward the study of a biphasic heterostructure, so I need to test the supercell of each single phase before deep diving in the heterostructure.

No, you do the simple thing first, and then you get to talk about doing the complicated thing.

actually, I have already collected data with the single cell, so this is actually the time to face the complicated thing, thank your advice by the way!

Then you have to tell us that this is the case in your original question, because it is easier for us to figure out what is the problem when we can compare the single cell with the supercell.

You can try by changing pseudopotential and rerun it
